# How can I search a file by its name and partial path?

Tags: linux, command-line, search, find

Often I have a file name and it's partial path, e.g. "content/docs/file.xml".

Is there a simple way to search for that file, without manually cutting into parts its name to provide directory name and file name separately?

It'd be great if `find` worked in that way, so I could run `find content/docs/file.xml`, but unfortunately it doesn't.

Comment: You could try adding a * wildcard at the beginning. `find -path *content/docs/file.xml` worked for me.

Comment: thanks, @Bob, it's really worked for me. Btw, interesting, that if I'm adding a slash after an asterisk: "find -path */content/docs/file.xml", it doesn't work. Thanks a lot anyway.

Comment: The reason the slash after asterisk didn't work is probably because the asterisk should have been escaped, see the edit to my answer.

Answer (score 139, accepted):

Pass in a `*` wildcard to indicate a match for *anything*. You also need to escape the `*`s, e.g.:

```
find . -path \*content/docs/file.xml
```

or enclose the pattern in quotes, e.g.:

```
find . -path "*content/docs/file.xml"
```

As the man page describes it:

> $ find . -name *.c -print
>
> find: paths must precede expression
>
> This  happens  because  *.c has been expanded by the shell resulting in
>      find actually receiving a command line like this:
>
> find . -name bigram.c code.c frcode.c locate.c -print
>
> That command is of course not going to work.  Instead of  doing  things
>      this  way, you should enclose the pattern in quotes or escape the wild‐
>      card:
>
> $ find . -name \*.c -print

Comment: example of how to find all Tomcat's folders on the server, then list full paths for all the files contained in the `WEB-INF/lib` folder of each web-app: `find $(find / -path '*/*tomcat*/webapps/*/WEB-INF/lib') -type f`

Answer (score 15):

find has a `-path` (or the equivalent but less portable `-wholename`) option too `find $top_dir -wholename *string*`

```
find /usr -path *in/abiw*

>/usr/bin/abiword
```

Comment: I don't know the full path, only partial, so "-wholename" won't work.

Comment: the flag is misleading, see my example... it just lets you extend the string into a directory if you know it

Answer (score 4):

```
find . -type f | grep "content/docs/file.xml"
```

or just

```
locate content/docs/file.xml
```

Comment: locate is an interesting option, but it searches the whole disk, I'd like to have an ability to specify the base search directory or at least to specify using param, that search should be made from this directory (like your first option does), not from the root.

Comment: @user69817 - on the contrary, locate doesn't search the disk, it interrogates a locate database, which typically gets populated via cron once a day.

Answer (score 2):

If you dont want to stay posix-compliant, at least on Linux you can also use the `-regex` (and `-regextype`) option for this purpose.

For instance:

```
find folder/ -regextype posix-extended -regex "(.*/)?deer/(.*/)?beer"
```

will match

```
folder/deer/beer
folder/deer/dir/forest/beer/
folder/forest/deer/dir/forest/beer/
```

etc.

See linux man for details.

Answer (score 0):

For example searching files in a location using asterisk/wildcard (`*`) as: 
`dir=“/apps/*/instance01/"`
you could use find `${dir} -name “*.jks”`.
putting all the files in an array like this:

```
arr=(`find ${dir} -name “*.jks"`)
```

if you want to get files with other extensions use ‘or’ like this:

`-name "*.keystore" -o -name "*.jks" -o -name “*.p12"`
because `-name` only accepts single string so use ‘or’.

Finally put everything in array like this:

```
arr=(`find ${dir} -name "*.keystore" -o -name "*.jks" -o -name "*.p12"`)
```

if you have full paths not the partial paths its much easier to put them in arrays like this:

```
arr=(“/Users/ajay/Documents/keystore_and_p12files/"*.{keystore,p12,jks})
```